# How to predict price with dummy variables ARIMAX in R?

Tags: forecasting, predictive-models, categorical-encoding

Can anyone help? I want to predict a price variable using five dummy variables. Data conditions:

1. contains an up-trend component
2. not stationary

I'm confused about whether to split the data or not. It's hard to find a definite answer, I've done a lot of research but couldn't find a suitable answer/syntax for my problem.